# Vapor unable to deploy to Heroku: We don't have build instructions for 5.3

Tags: swift, heroku, vapor

I was able to commit the changes to my Heroku repo but when I push it it shows the following errors:

```
  remote: Compressing source files... done.
        remote: Building source:
        remote: 
        remote: -----> Swift app detected
        remote: -----> Using Swift 5.3 (from .swift-version file)
        remote: -----> Using built-in clang (Swift 5.3)
        remote: -----> Installing swiftenv
        remote: -----> Installing Swift 5.3
        remote: We don't have build instructions for 5.3.
        remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Swift app.
        remote: 
        remote:  !     Push failed
```

I used the following commands:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

I also changed  the buildpack to `vapor/vapor`:

```
heroku buildpacks:set vapor/vapor
```

Why is this error happening, and how can I fix it?

I have even changed the swift version by following commands

```
 echo "5.1.3" > .swift-version
git add .                    
git commit -m "Done"
```

and pushed it but it to Heroku shows the following error

```
package at '/tmp/build_8e6b47bc' is using Swift tools version 5.2.0 but the installed version is 5.1.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift 5.3 [doesn't appear to have been released yet](https://swift.org/download/), and the only Vapor buildpacks that I can find don't yet support it.

I think you're using [this buildpack](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/deploy/heroku/#swift-version-file) that uses Swift version `5.1.3` in its current documentation. Try reducing your Swift version to that (by editing your `.swift-version` file and committing) and redeploying.

**Edit:** Your new error indicates a Swift Tools version mismatch. I don't program in Swift, but [it looks like this is defined by a line in your `Package.swift` file](https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/spm/#tools-version) and that it is related to your Swift version:

> The very first line of a package manifest indicates the Swift tools version required. This specifies the minimum version of Swift that the package supports. The Package description API may also change between Swift versions, so this line ensures Swift will know how to parse your manifest.

Try changing

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.2
```

to

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.1
```

then commit and redeploy.

I also recommend making sure that you are using the same version of Swift locally for development as you're targeting on the server.

Comment: Ok what command i should use for it and is it possible to specify different version of Swift or I should change the project swift version

Comment: @Stark2022, I always recommend using the same versions of everything in development and production whenever possible. Please see my updated answer.